# Is there notation for the larger of two sets by cardinality/size?

Tags: notation

As the title says, suppose I have sets $X= \{ 1, 2, 3,10\}$ and $Y=\{199, 8\}$, then is there an accepted notation to choose $X$?

Something like: $\max_{|\cdot|}(X, Y) = X$ ?

Comment: Do you mean "larger"? Because $X$ has greater cardinality than $Y$ ... (Incidentally, I don't know of any such notation.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber yes, fixed it.

Comment: You can always define such a function: $\tau(X,Y)= \left\{\; X,\;\textrm{card}(X) \geq \textrm{card}(Y);\quad Y,\;\textrm{card}(X) < \textrm{card}(Y) \right. $. But sadly, no, there is no standard notation for what you have in mind. Also keep in mind that the function would return the first set should they be equipotent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\operatorname{argmax}$ is the notation you're looking for. Whereas $\max$ gives the maximum output value, $\operatorname{argmax}$ gives the input value which produces the maximum.

So you would say $\operatorname{argmax}_{S} (|S|)$.